# DIV compatible issues IE

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create web page with section on it, with a title, a paragraph of text and a logo in each section.

I am using the below code, which works for IE11, but I am having compatibity errors in different broswers. Some IE browers show extra space above the section divs and other users have reported the text disappearing as you scroll up/down the page.

Can anyone suggest any improvemtents for my code, to mitigate these compatibility issues

HTML

```
<!--START CONTENT-->        
<div id="content">

    <!--START OF SECTION-->
    <div id="first" class="">
    <div id="centercontain">

    <!--TITLE-->
    <div id="" class="lefttitle">
    <h1>Virtualisation<h1>
    </div>

                <!--SUB MENU-->
                 <div id="prodnavcontain">

                    <a href="#vsphere"><div class="title2">
                    <div class="triangle"></div>
                        VMware vSphere
                    </div></a>

                    <a href="#hyper"><div class="title2">
                    <div class="triangle"></div>
                        Microsoft Hyper-V
                    </div></a>

                    <a href="#san"><div class="title2">
                    <div class="triangle"></div>
                        SAN & NAS Storage
                    </div></a>

                    <a href="#"><div class="title2">
                    <div class="triangle"></div>
                        Datacentre Networking
                    </div></a>

                    <a href="#"><div class="title2">
                    <div class="triangle"></div>
                        Backup and Disaster Recovery
                    </div></a>

                    <a href="#"><div class="title2">
                    <div class="triangle"></div>
                        Offsite Failover 
                    </div></a>  
                  </div> <!-- END OF SUB MENU-->

        <!--DETAIL-->
        <div id="" class="leftdetail">
        <p>Virtualisation first gained popularity as a tool for server consolidation. Large fleets of aging servers were virtualised onto a handful of modern servers providing far better resource utilisation. Fast-forward and Virtualisation now enables rapid deployment, reliability and new ways of working automated provisioning, virtual machine replication and virtual desktop.<br><br>
        With increased reliance on virtualisation, it is important to choose server, storage and network components deployed in configurations which have been tested for compatibility and performance.<br><br>
        Using Indigo's experience ensures that you get maximum performance and reliability from your virtualisation deployment, properly integrated into your existing IT infrastructure.
        </p>

        </div>  <!--END OF DETAIL-->
        </div>  <!--END CENTER CONTAIN-->
        </div>  <!-- END OF SECTION-->

        <!--START OF SECTION-->
        <div id="vsphere" class="">
        <div id="centercontain">

        <!--TITLE-->
        <div id="" class="lefttitle">
        <h1>VMware vSphere<h1>
        </div>

        <!--DETAIL-->
        <div id="" class="leftdetail">

            <!--GRAPHIC-->
            <div id="vmpiccon">
            <img src="../images/vmware_vsphere.png" alt="vSphere" height="190" width="190">
            </div>

        <p>Virtualisation first gained popularity as a tool for server consolidation. Large fleets of aging servers were virtualised onto a handful of modern servers providing far better resource utilisation. Fast-forward and Virtualisation now enables rapid deployment, reliability and new ways of working automated provisioning, virtual machine replication and virtual desktop.<br><br>
        With increased reliance on virtualisation, it is important to choose server, storage and network components deployed in configurations which have been tested for compatibility and performance.<br><br>
        Using Indigo's experience ensures that you get maximum performance and reliability from your virtualisation deployment, properly integrated into your existing IT infrastructure.
        </p>

        </div>  <!--END OF DETAIL-->
        </div>  <!--END CENTER CONTAIN-->
        </div>  <!-- END OF SECTION-->  

        <!--START OF SECTION--> 
        <div id="hyper" class="">
        <div id="centercontain">

        <!--TITLE-->
        <div id="" class="righttitle">
        <h1>Microsoft Hyper-V<h1>
        </div>

        <!--DETAIL-->
        <div id="" class="rightdetail">

        <p>Virtualisation first gained popularity as a tool for server consolidation. Large fleets of aging servers were virtualised onto a handful of modern servers providing far better resource utilisation. Fast-forward and Virtualisation now enables rapid deployment, reliability and new ways of working automated provisioning, virtual machine replication and virtual desktop.<br><br>
        With increased reliance on virtualisation, it is important to choose server, storage and network components deployed in configurations which have been tested for compatibility and performance.<br><br>
        Using Indigo's experience ensures that you get maximum performance and reliability from your virtualisation deployment, properly integrated into your existing IT infrastructure.
        </p>

            <!--GRAPHIC-->
            <div id="hyperpiccon">
            <img src="../images/hyperv.png" alt="vSphere" height="225" width="225">
            </div>

        </div>  <!--END OF DETAIL-->
        </div>  <!--END CENTER CONTAIN-->
        </div>  <!-- END OF SECTION-->

        <!--START OF SECTION-->
        <div id="san" class="">
        <div id="centercontain">

        <!--TITLE-->
        <div id="" class="lefttitle">
        <h1>SAN & NAS Storage <h1>
        </div>

        <!--DETAIL-->
        <div id="" class="leftdetail">

            <!--GRAPHIC-->
            <div id="sanpiccon">
            <img src="../images/san.png" alt="vSphere" height="115" width="115">
            </div>

        <p>Virtualisation first gained popularity as a tool for server consolidation. Large fleets of aging servers were virtualised onto a handful of modern servers providing far better resource utilisation. Fast-forward and Virtualisation now enables rapid deployment, reliability and new ways of working automated provisioning, virtual machine replication and virtual desktop.<br><br>
        With increased reliance on virtualisation, it is important to choose server, storage and network components deployed in configurations which have been tested for compatibility and performance.<br><br>
        Using Indigo's experience ensures that you get maximum performance and reliability from your virtualisation deployment, properly integrated into your existing IT infrastructure.
        </p>

        </div>  <!--END OF DETAIL-->
        </div>  <!--END CENTER CONTAIN-->
        </div>  <!-- END OF SECTION-->

    </div> <!-- END OF CONTENT-->
```

CSS

```
#content {
padding: 0px;
padding-bottom:0px;   /* Height of the footer element */
}


#bottombar {
    background-color: #dfdfdf;
    border-top: 1px solid #a4a4a4;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #fff;
    height: 35px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}


#prodnavcontain {
    float: right;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    top: -33px;
    width: 159px;
}

.triangle {
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #464646;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 6px 0 6px 10px;
    height: 0;
    margin-left: 244px;
    margin-top: 19px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
}

#centercontain{

    width: 990px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#first{
    height: 350px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #464646;
    top: 0px;

}

#vsphere{
    height: 350px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #ededed;
    top: 0px;
}

#hyper{
    height: 350px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
    top: 0px;
}

#san{
    height: 350px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #ededed;
    top: 0px;
}


.lefttitle{
    top: 32px;
    left: 0px;
    position: relative;

}

.righttitle{
    top: 32px;
    padding-left: 296px;
    position: relative;

}

.leftdetail {
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 62px;
    width: 695px;
}


.rightdetail {
    left: 297px;
    position: relative;
    top: 62px;
    width: 695px;
}


#vmpiccon {
    left: 747px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -19px;
}

#hyperpiccon {
    left: -301px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -47px;
}


#sanpiccon {
    left: 797px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 24px;
}


.title2 {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #464646;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 58px;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 58px;
    opacity: 0.85;
    padding-left: 10px;
    position: static;
    text-align: left;
    top: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 280px;
}

    .title2:hover {

    background-color: #fff;
    filter: alpha(opacity=95);
    opacity: .95;
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

PS. A copy of my DEV page can be found here: http://goo.gl/ww0hse

Thanks,

Comment: I don't think vaguely describing a bunch of issues and dumping your entire code is going to help much.

Comment: "Some IE browers show extra space above the section divs and other users have reported the text disappearing as you scroll up/down the page."

Comment: Interested to know if my code can be improved, I am new to HTML. I suspect my coding techniques are to blame for the compatibility issues - I am looking for some best practice advice.

Comment: I can give you two tips. `<div>` in not a valid element inside a `<a>`, use `<span>` instead if you want to style. Also use one `<h1>`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position: relative;` from `#wrapper` in `style.css(line 20)`

```
#wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*position: relative;*/
}
```